# i have an excel file that i need to import in the database table

Tags: php, mysql, excel

i have an excel file that i need to import in the database table called markers, markers has 4 columns coresponding with the columns in the excel file, my import works very file but i want to add a functionality where by if i add new columns in my excel file and import, the application reads the file and automatically generates the new columns in the markers table as  passed from the excel file. thanks alot in Advance. Language am using is php + mysql, but any suggestions are welcome... Thanks

Comment: compare headings with field names (`DESCRIBE #table#` can give you the existing fields) if extra columns exist do:`ALTER TABLE #table# ADD #newfield# TEXT NOT NULL` which creates the new field (I have used TEXT as we have no idea what the data is going to be)

Comment: Waygood that gret... am not so good in php how can i do that in a simple sql or php code.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar needs some months ago. [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is what you need.

Easy to implement, well documented and with many examples.

Hope that helps.

Update: As far as I understand, I recommend you to read the titles of the excel columns, and look if every excel column already exists in the table.
In case that doesnt exists, add the field, and then insert data.

Do you have any column that can be used as an index ? any column is unique in the table, as an Id, customer_number or anything?

Please answer this and I'll share some code.

Comment: gret library GUiLTY thks, but has to much staff, have looked at different examples in it for 2 gud hours bt failed to get a solution to my problem...

Comment: ok. can you detail more which is EXACTLY your problem? Maybe I can write a small snippet to solve it.

Comment: miguel i have a table with 4 columns, and a php script that import an excel file data into that table, it all works file but am in a situation where by i need one to be able to add more columns of their choice in the excel file and when its imported the new columns in the exel file the new columns are automatically added into the mysql table...